# Any way to simulate MotionEvent.transform(Matrix) in Android API level 8 or 9?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I noticed that in Android API Level 11 (ICS) [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#transform%28android.graphics.Matrix%29) has a `transform` method that takes a `Matrix`. This would actually make something I'm doing somewhat cleaner, but I'm coding for Level 8.

Is there a convenient alternative to `MotionEvent.transform()` that works on earlier versions of Android? I'd like historical and multi-touch coordinates to all be transformed, and I'd like it to correctly handle the distinction between relative versus absolute coordinates, which is where things get kind of tricky.

What I really want to know is if can I create a `MotionEvent` that's a transformed copy of another `MotionEvent`. I actually don't need arbitrary transformations, but I need to be able to both translate and scale. I believe I can translate with `offsetLocation`, but I don't see any way to scale a `MotionEvent` (prior to Level 11). In particular, how can I transform the coordinates of a multi-touch event? The `obtain` methods just take a single (x,y) pair, not an array.

The reason I want to do this is that I have one object that dispatches events to a set of "child" objects. Right now each of those children transforms the coordinates in a kind of ad hoc way. The parent (the dispatcher) knows what transformation needs to be performed, however, so it would be a lot cleaner to just transform the `MotionEvent` (or a copy) before dispatching it to the children. Alternatively I could create my own class that either wraps the `MotionEvent` or copies and transforms the data out of a `MotionEvent`, but it would be a lot simpler if I could use a `MotionEvent`.

Comment: Only thing you could do is calculate the transform yourself. Should be trivial using the Matrix class.

Comment: @aleph_null Yes, but can I actually populate a `MotionEvent` with the transformed coordinates? I don't see any way to set more that one pair of (x,y) coordinates. How do I transform a multi-touch event?

Comment: im not sure if it'll work, but maybe you could create a MotionEvent using MotionEvent.obtain and several addBatch calls. Transform each set of x,y coordinates independently.

Comment: @aleph_null As far as I can tell, that only lets you set the historical coordinates. There does not appear to be any way to set multi-touch coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As best as I can tell, the answer is "no". There does not appear to be any way to manipulate the coordinates of any pointerId other than the first one in a `MotionEvent` in pre-Honeycomb versions of Android.

The workaround I came up with was to create my own wrapper class (which I happened to call `TouchEvent`) and use this instead of `MotionEvent` when delegating `onTouch`. This wouldn't work if I was implementing some standard interface, but in my case I controlled the interface of my delegates, so this solution works well enough.